# Determinant of Word Matrix

Tags: mathematics, letters

Challenge: Create a 3x3 matrix of letters (NO REPEATS) such that the determinant of the matrix forms words from the 'multiplications'. For example, in a simple 2x2 case, take the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}O & I\\N & R\end{bmatrix}$

the determinant of which is OR-IN. This forms 2 2-letter words. In the case of a 3x3, you will end up with 6 3-letter words if done correctly.

Don't know how to find the determinant of a matrix? Fear not, here's the guide (or read a more detailed explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)):

$|A| = \begin{vmatrix} a & b & c\\d & e & f\\g & h & i \end{vmatrix} = a\begin{vmatrix} e & f\\h & i \end{vmatrix} - b\begin{vmatrix} d & f\\g & i \end{vmatrix} + c\begin{vmatrix} d & e\\g & h \end{vmatrix} = aei+bfg+cdh-ceg-bdi-afh .
$

If that looks too complicated, [here's another method](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/determs2.htm) that some find easier.

Don't worry about the additions and subtractions, I'm only concerned with the words formed. <s>That said, if your words could be added and subtracted as base 26 numbers according to the determinant and result in a valid word, I would be incredibly impressed (a 100 reputation impressed, even).</s> (This is mathematically impossible, determinant is always 0; sorry to get your hopes up). As usual, words are considered valid iff they are English words found on dictionary.com (read: this does not include (pre/suf)fixes, abbreviations, acronyms, etc.)

Comment: You may want to add a rule you cannot use the same letters in each column. As the rules are now, pick any three letter word and write it in all columns. Result is 6 times said word, and would make a valid answer. EDIT: never mind, I missed the 'no repeats' part.

Comment: @TimCouwelier Good looking out, but I specify no repeated letters in the first sentence of the puzzle.

Comment: Also, for anyone attempting this: just repeat the first two columns on the right of the 3x3 block. The 'words' are any diagonal length 3 line in that block, read from top to bottom.

Comment: Damnit.. I was about to post an answer, then realised I had ONE repeating letter. (O S B / I R P / A T T make for ort, spa, bit, bra, opt and sit)

Comment: @TimCouwelier thanks for mentioning that, I've added a link to the explanation of that method for those who prefer

Comment: No repeats means you can't do $\begin{bmatrix}Z & Z & Z\\Z & Z & Z\\Z & Z & Z\end{bmatrix}$ :(

Comment: Now answers are popping up left and right. Once you realise you mostly need vowels in the middle row, the first part is actually surprisingly easy. The latter however... :)

Comment: If you treat the words as three-digit base 26 numbers instead of products, your "determinant" will always be zero because every letter is added and subtracted equally.

Comment: @f'' I juust realized it before you commented. Been too long since Linear Algebra I guess :/

Comment: Would be interesting to see if in any of the examples concatenating the six three letter words could form a sentence of sorts.

Comment: I thought I'd try this without using any vowels in the middle row -- it turns out it's *a lot* harder!

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain In that case, you should post it as a separate puzzle! Hopefully it will last longer than mine did :)

Comment: @NeedAName Thanks!  I [just did](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/word-matrices-level-2).  We'll see how long it lasts...

Comment: Hmm, why the HNQ prevention?

Comment: @Anachor I don't understand your question. Did I prevent it somehow?

Comment: @NeedAName there is a `${}$` in your title, [which prevents HNQ](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/questions-can-be-manually-removed-from-hnqs).

Comment: Well, I had no idea, I just couldn't come up a title that met 15 characters. Thanks for pointing that out (not that I imagine this question is making it up there, what with a whopping 86 views and 2 upvotes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

> $\begin{bmatrix} B & S & L\\I & A & U\\M & D & T \end{bmatrix}$

This produces the following words:

> **BAT**
>  **SUM**
>  **LID**
>  **LAM**
>  **BUD**
>  **SIT**

Comment: As the first person to submit a valid answer, I'm accepting yours. Nicely done!

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{bmatrix}F & C & P\\A & O & U\\T & N & B\end{bmatrix}$

making the words FOB, FUN, CAB, CUT, PAN, and POT. Each column on its own is also a word.

Answer (score 4):

**A simple idea to generate solutions**

Let the matrix be-

$\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\\d & e & f\\g & h & i \end{bmatrix}$

Then we need the following to be valid words.

```
aei afh bdi bfg cdh ceg
```

This can be treated as a substitution cipher and solved using a brute force dictionary search.  This produces lots of solutions. [Here are 954 solutions](http://pastebin.com/5ddTQP8C). I stopped there because the engine I was using only shows top 1000 results (of which 954 were unique).

**Edit:**

I also tried a 4x4 matrix search. It didn't produce any complete result but some got close. The searching key is:

```
AFKP AFLO AGJP AGLN AHJO AHKN BEKP BELO BGIP BGLM BHIO BHKM CEJP CELN CFIP CFLM CHIN CHJM DEJO DEKN DFIO DFKM DGIN DGJM.
```

[Try here at quipquip](http://quipqiup.com/). However it might be possible if we allow some repetitions., which I haven't tried yet.

Comment: That's a really cool application! So I'm curious, what happens if you try on a 4x4 matrix (I've been trying to see if it's possible). The resulting words are: A(FKP GLN HJO HKN GJP FLO) B(EKP GLM HIN HKM GIP ELO) 
C(EJP FLM HIN HJM FIP ELN) D(EJO FKM GIN GJM FIO EKN). Let me know if you have the time/energy to try it out

Comment: quipqiup managed to get through the Cs with  
`CARE CONS CULT CURS COLE CANT MIRE MONK MUDS MURK MODE MINT BILE BANK BUDS BULK BADE BINS`, but didn't produce any valid solutions for the full matrix.

Answer (score 3):

To join the gang, here's what I came up with:

> $\begin{bmatrix}H & C & N\\A & I & O\\P & G & T\end{bmatrix}$

Makes:

> HIT, COP, NAG, NIP, HOG and CAT

Also note that:

> The columns in this matrix, just like f'' his answer, form words on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Sooo, this riddle was stuck in my head for a while, because I really wanted to get a whole sentence in that matrix. Unfortunately it is not perfect yet, hopefuly others have any ideas to fix it.

So here is the matrix.

$|A| = \begin{vmatrix} i & a & o\\r & t & n\\f & g & m \end{vmatrix}$

Leading to

> It Man Forgot Farming

Cheers!