# Word Matrices, Level 2

Tags: mathematics, word, letters

*This puzzle is based on [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)'s recent puzzle,  **[Determinant of Word Matrix](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22502/word-matrices)**.*

---

The challenge:

> Create a $3\times3$ matrix of distinct letters (i.e. no repeated letters) ***with no vowels in the middle row*** such that the six terms generated when calculating the determinant form valid English words.
>
> *Words are considered valid **if and only if they are English words found on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com)** (not including (pre/suf)fixes, abbreviations, acronyms, proper names, etc.).*

For example, with a simple $2\times2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}O & I\\N & R\end{bmatrix}$, the determinant is $OR-IN$.
This forms two 2-letter words.

---

With a $3\times3$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} A & B & C\\D & E & F\\G & H & I \end{bmatrix}$
 you will end up with six 3-letter words:

$AEI + BFG + CDH -CEG - BDI - AFH$.

Since the actual determinant doesn't matter, the easiest way to think of this is as a $3\times5$ matrix with the first two columns repeated:

$\begin{bmatrix} A & B & C & A & B\\D & E & F & D & E\\G & H & I & G & H \end{bmatrix}$

Then you just need to make sure all the intact diagonals $\searrow$ and $\swarrow$ are valid words.

---

*(For more information on finding determinants, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) or [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/determs2.htm))*

Comment: +1 for superior formatting! I should have you organize my puzzles before posting them :)

Comment: Haven't you over-complicated the puzzle? The last para is enough to understand the question by itself.

Comment: @ghosts I considered that, but it just seems really arbitrary to ask for a $3\times5$ matrix with certain repeated columns that fits a certain pattern.  I thought keeping the determinant explanation in there would help people understand where the idea came from, so it's not quite so arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a list of three-letter words and an automated search:

$\begin{bmatrix} A & I & O\\F & D & C\\E & T & S \end{bmatrix}$
producing the words ADS, ACT, IFS, ICE, OFT, and ODE.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/NGRPGWrx) are all 50 results my program found.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you found this, or did you just brute force it?

Comment: I suppose I should have added a [tag:no-computers] tag (since that was my intention), but kudos for finding 50 different solutions!